# Using redux data in the useEffect hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am now trying to call an API using data from the redux store.

Let say I got 2 API calls, `Api A` and `Api B` Inside the parent component I already called the `API A` and save the data inside the redux already.

Now I am in another component. I need to call `Api B`. But API B has a `params`, which I will get from `API A`. So Inside the Second component, I am using `useEffect` hook to call the data.

To get the params from the redux, I am using `useSelector` Hook.

Inside the second component, UseEffect Hook is something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
      let splitText = cartList?.OrderDTO?.DeliveryCountry;
      let deliveryAddressId = splitText?.split(',');
      if (cartList.OrderDTO?.DeliveryCountry !== '') {
        dispatch(getShippingMethodById(token.access_token, deliveryAddressId));
      } else {
        dispatch(
          getShippingMethodById(
            token.access_token,
            cartList.OrderDTO?.CustomerAddressId,
          ),
    }
}, []);
```

So in the `useEffect` hook, I got the `deliveryAddressId` from redux. To draw in data from the redux into component, I am using `useSelector` hook

```
let cartList = useSelector((state) => state.productReducer.cartList);
```

The problem is that I always get `undefined` for `cartlist` when ever I tried to access it inside the `useEffect` hook

So the dispatch called are always getting undefined. So What can I do to make this hooks works?

Comment: you need to add `cartlist` in useEffect dependancy array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `cartList` to your dependency array, so the `useEffect` hook watches for updates to that piece of state. As it is written now, the `useEffect` only runs on the first render, where `cartList` is probably `undefined`.
[React - useEffect Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

```js
useEffect(() => {
      let splitText = cartList?.OrderDTO?.DeliveryCountry;
      let deliveryAddressId = splitText?.split(',');
      if (cartList.OrderDTO?.DeliveryCountry !== '') {
        dispatch(getShippingMethodById(token.access_token, deliveryAddressId));
      } else {
        dispatch(
          getShippingMethodById(
            token.access_token,
            cartList.OrderDTO?.CustomerAddressId,
          ),
    }
}, [cartList]); // Add 'cartList' to your dependency array here
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution is that you add `cartList` inside the dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // All your logic inside
}, [cartList]);
```

*I don't have info about the complete parent-child component structure, but from what I understood with the error I can explain the issue.*

You are using `[]`, for `useEffect` dependency, which means the callback inside `useEffect` will be triggered only once when the component mounts.

It is possible that when your component mounted, the API call in the parent was not complete, and you have still have `undefined` in store for `cartList`.

> To check this hypothesis you can add `console.log` in API response and
> inside the `useEffect`.

What else you can do?

You can not render the child component until you have data from the API call.

**Why adding `cartList` in the dependency array fixed the issue?**

> By dependency array inside useEffect, your useEffect call back will be
> called whenever the values in the dependency array change + on the
> mount.

So, at the time of mount of the child component, useEffect's callback will trigger (cartList as undefined), then when the API call is successful and after that data is pushed in state, your child component will rerender and will retrigger the callback inside `useEffect` with the actual(which you got from API and pushed in store) `cartList` data.